# how refresh/reload web page from another browser

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, signalr, signalr.client

I want open this web app on different browsers then do some actions in one of them (ex run some post request) next I want that in all other browsers page will be reloaded

I'm not completely sure, but, perhaps, "signalR javascript client" will help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> open this web app on different browsers then do some actions in one of them (ex run some post request) next I want that in all other browsers page will be reloaded

> perhaps, "signalR javascript client" will help me?

Yes, you can achieve it by integrating ASP.NET Core SignalR functionality into your project to push specific notification to connected [SignalR JavaScript clients](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/signalr/javascript-client?view=aspnetcore-5.0#call-client-methods-from-the-hub), then the JavaScript client can update DOM content or refresh current page once received that specific notification message.

Besides, if it requires sending notification message from controller action(s) in your development scenario, you can inject an instance of `IHubContext` in your controller, then use that instance to send message(s) to client(s) as if you were in the hub itself.

For detailed information about "Send messages from outside a hub", please check this doc:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/signalr/hubcontext?view=aspnetcore-5.0#inject-an-instance-of-ihubcontext-in-a-controller

Answer (score 1):

You can do that using the tech you mention. There are many options. Do you know anything about asp.net core/ Signalr? I ask because you have different SDKs available meaning you can do the same thing in C#, javascript, javaa, etc, using the same platform, a static web app for example.

You really do have a lot of choice. Also, have a look at FluidFramework, it's microsoft open source and pretty cool.

https://fluidframework.com/